# SVG circle element in Leaflet Legend

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am wondering the simplest way to add an SVG circle in a leaflet legend.  I don't need it to update size, I just want a circle with some specified radius (doesn't really matter the size) and a specified color.  I have three different map layers, with different colored points being displayed in each.

I have three checkboxes where I can toggle these layers, and I want each checkbox to display a different colored circle below it to indicate which layer is being turned on/off.  Below is my script for the checkboxes, and I'm able to get a circle to show up as an SVG element.  However, I don't want it to attach to the 'panel', but rather, I want to attach three separate SVG's under each of the checkboxes (or next to).  Here's my code:

```
$('#panel').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxCity3" class="Cities3" id="showResidents" value="true" checked="checked" style="-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #383838; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #383838; box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #383838; background-color:#FFF; -moz-border-radius:8px; -webkit-border-radius:8px; border-radius:8px; display:inline-block; cursor:pointer; color:#000000; font-family:avenir; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; padding:8px 14px; text-decoration:none;">Show Residents</button>');
    $('#panel').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxCity" class="Cities" id="showFellows" value="true" checked="checked" style="-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #383838; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #383838; box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #383838; background-color:#FFF; -moz-border-radius:8px; -webkit-border-radius:8px; border-radius:8px; display:inline-block; cursor:pointer; color:#000000; font-family:avenir; font-size:1px; font-weight:bold; padding:8px 14px; text-decoration:none;">Show Fellows</button>');
    $('#panel').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxCity2" class="Cities2" id="showResidentFellows" value="true" checked="checked" style="-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #383838; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #383838; box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #383838; background-color:#FFF; -moz-border-radius:8px; -webkit-border-radius:8px; border-radius:8px; display:inline-block; cursor:pointer; color:#000000; font-family:avenir; font-size:1px; font-weight:bold; padding:8px 14px; text-decoration:none;">Show Residents/<br>Fellows</button>');
    d3.select('#panel').append("svg").attr("width", 60).attr("height", 60).append("circle").attr("cx", 25).attr("cy", 25).attr("r", 25).style("fill", "purple");
```

However, if I attempt to append circle to actual checkboxes, it doesn't work:

```
      d3.select('#checkboxCity3').append("svg").attr("width", 60).attr("height", 60).append("circle").attr("cx", 25).attr("cy", 25).attr("r", 25).style("fill", "purple");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That happens because HTML `input` elements are not allowed to have content. See reference:

> Permitted content: None, it is an empty element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input